# telegram webhook syn ack rst

Tags: telegram

После смены домена с .info на .ru пришлось двигать бота.
После выключения webHook с одного домена и включении на другом начались проблемы.
Сервер стоит дома. Анализируя логи прихожу к выводу, что всё работает, телеграм пытается попасть на сервер и сам же сбрасывает соединение. Кто-нибудь может прояснить из-за чего такое может быть? Вот кусочек лога:

```
TCP: 149.154.167.214(32362) -> 192.168.0.2(443) Seq 3592766463.(0) SYN 
TCP: 192.168.0.2(443) -> 149.154.167.214(32362) Seq 4031636035.(0) ACK 3592766464 SYN 
TCP: 149.154.167.214(32362) -> 192.168.0.2(443) Seq 3592766464.(0) RST 
New TCP connection #10: 149.154.167.214(32362) <-> 192.168.0.2(443)
10    0.0162 (0.0162)  C>S  TCP RST
TCP: 149.154.167.214(32362) -> 192.168.0.2(443) Seq 3592766464.(0) RST 
TCP: 149.154.167.214(32362) -> 192.168.0.2(443) Seq 3592766464.(0) ACK 4031636036 
TCP: 192.168.0.2(443) -> 149.154.167.214(32362) Seq 4031636036.(0) RST 
TCP: 149.154.167.214(32362) -> 192.168.0.2(443) Seq 3592766464.(201) ACK 4031636036 PUSH 
TCP: 192.168.0.2(443) -> 149.154.167.214(32362) Seq 4031636036.(0) RST
```

Comment: Сертификат заменить не забыли?)

Comment: Конечно не забыл. Но дело тут совсем не в этом. До сертификата, если я не ошибаюсь тут дело-то и не доходит вообще. Кроме того изредка сообщения от бота проскакивают, но в очереди сообщений телеграмма не убираются... Может телегу как-то блокировать хитро научились... Хотя без всяких прокси на смарте работает без тормозов...

Comment: Когда дело доходит до сертификата выглядит это примерно так: TCP: 109.70.100.25(59313) -> 192.168.0.2(443) Seq 2035442694.(0) SYN
TCP: 192.168.0.2(443) -> 109.70.100.25(59313) Seq 4083082618.(0) ACK 2035442695 SYN
TCP: 109.70.100.25(59313) -> 192.168.0.2(443) Seq 2035442695.(0) ACK 4083082619
New TCP connection #1: 109.70.100.25(59313) <-> 192.168.0.2(443)
TCP: 109.70.100.25(59313) -> 192.168.0.2(443) Seq 2035442695.(517) ACK 4083082619 PUSH
1 1  0.2377 (0.2377)  C>S  Handshake
      ClientHello
        Version 3.3
        resume [32]=

Comment: очень интересно выглядит трассировка маршрута до сервера телеграмм. На пути сервера постоянно меняются, а до конца так и не доходит, но пинг идёт... Возможно такое поведение это побочка... Если откусить два пакета со сбросом соединения, я думаю всё бы заработало... Может кто подскажет как с помощью iptables или ещё чего отрезать эти пакеты?

Answer (score 0):

Почитал про iptables. Добавил такое правило

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 149.154.167.214 -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK RST -j DROP
```

и всё заработало.
Очень костыльный метод какой-то получился... Очень он мне не нравится, может есть вариант лучше?